# Combine multiple LINQ entities into one entity including top related record

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have 2 tables called Person and Activity. Each person can have multiple Activities.

The fields in Person are PersonId, Name, Age.
The fields in Activity are ActivityId, PersonId, Description, StartDate, EndDate, Flag

I have created a new Entity called PersonAndLatestActivity which has some similarly named fields from Person and Activity. ie PersonId, Name, Age, Description, StartDate, EndDate, Flag

How do I project each person and their LATEST activity into the PersonAndLatestActivity entity?

I need achieve this using LINQ for Entities as I'm using EF4 Code First ie:-

```
public IQueryable<PersonAndLatestActivity> GetAllPeopleAndLatestActivityList()
{
    var result = (from x in db.People
        select new 
        {

        }                
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you could do this as a queryable, but if it helps this is how I'd do it with objects:

```
public IQueryable<PersonAndLatestActivity> GetAllPeopleAndLatestActivityList()
{
    List<PersonAndLatestActivity> list = new List<PersonAndLatestActivity>();
    foreach(person in db.People.ToList()){
        var act = db.Activity.Where(x=>x.PersonId == person.PersonId).OrderBy(x=>x.Date).Single();
        list.Add(new PersonAndLatestActivity{
            PersonId = person.PersonId,
            ActivityId = act.ActivityId,
            etc...
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
from p in db.People
from a in p.Activities.OrderByDescending(act => act.StartDate).Take(1)
select new PersonAndLatestActivity { p.PersonId, ..., a.StartDate, ... }
```

assuming that there is a navigation property `p.Activities`, otherwise you should use a join.